# Oracle on Docker :: Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE. SP2-0640: Not connected

Tags: oracle, docker, sqlplus, oracle19c

In the screenshot below you can see how I can successfully connect to the database but the command is rejected because... I'm not connected to the database...

1. I login into SQL*Plus and I receive the confirmation I'm connected: `Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.3.0.0.0`
2. Just to be sure I re-enter the connection: `connect SYSTEM/SYSTEM@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB` and I receive as a response `Connected.`
3. I follow the official instruction of [Oracle Database Sample Schemas](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas) and I run `@/home/oracle/db-sample-schemas-master/mksample.sql systempw syspw hrpw oepw pmpw ixpw shpw bipw users temp /var/opt/oracle/log/ localhost:1521/ORCLCDB` and here is when things start to get nasty.

First I receive an `ERROR: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`.

Then a `Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE. SP2-0640: Not connected`

[image]

How can it be, that is the Administrator password.

Should I grant anything else to this user?

Comment: Your `connect` says the system password is `SYSTEM`, not `systempw`... are you supplying actual valid values or the placeholder/example values from the documentation?

Comment: Make sure you're running the script in Pluggable database assuming `ORCLCDB` is root container database

Comment: @AlexPoole: SYSTEM is also the password

Comment: @Kumar, I'm new to Oracle, ORCLCDB is definitely the root container database so what should I do?

Comment: login as Sysdba and type `show pdbs`,that will list any pluggable database.Use that pdb name as connection identifier e,g if `orclpdb` is PDB try to login as `sys/passwd@orclpdb` or from root container you can switch to PDB `alter session set container=orclpdb`

Answer (score 0):

The "no longer connected" warning is simply because the script issued its own `connect` that failed with ORA-01017. A connect attempt necessarily disconnects the current session first, so when the new connection fails there is no active connection at all. You have to reconnect successfully to be able to do anything useful.

The documentation you linked to says:

> Start SQL*Plus and run the top level installation script as discussed in README.txt:
>
> ```
> sqlplus system/systempw@connect_string
> @mksample systempw syspw hrpw oepw pmpw ixpw shpw bipw users temp /your/path/to/log/ connect_string
> ```
>
> Note: Use an absolute path and also append a trailing slash to the log directory name.
>
> Use your current SYSTEM and SYS passwords, and also your actual default and temporary tablespace names. The passwords for the new HR, OE, PM, IX, SH and BI users will be set to the values you specify.

You have to supply your actual current password for the SYSTEM and SYS accounts, not the examples in that command; and sensible password for the new sample-schema accounts that will be created. For example, from your successful `connect`, the first argument to `@mksample` should be `SYSTEM` rather than the example `systempw`.

Comment: my password for SYSTEM is SYSTEM, I've used it to connect as you can see from the screenshot in the green box

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani - yes, but then you still used `systempw` in the `@mksample` call.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Poole, so what user/password should I use instead?

Comment: Well, like the doc says, the actual passwords for your SYSTEM and SYS accounts. You haven't said what your SYS password is, but you need to use `SYSTEM` instead of `systempw`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to load the sample schemas inside oracle database inside the docker container using the [guide](https://github.com/oracle-samples/db-sample-schemas/tree/32f242c6b06abc3fe662f74d36d02d471e2fc32d#25--run-the-installation-script). What worked for me was to use `localhost:1521/ORCLPDB1` as connection string in place of the SID. After this all of the tables got loaded.